# How to open this iBrightness portable app, or any portable app and replace it's resources?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, notification-area, portable

I wanna ask how to crack open portable apps and replace their resource using tools like Resource Hacker. I've tried most of the most popular Resource replaces/modifier/hacker on Windows, I've get to successfully replace resources on most portable apps except this one. [iBrightness](http://download.cnet.com/iBrightness/3000-2094_4-75912934.html). My intention here is to change mainly it's system tray icon. I've tried it on Resource hacker but it won't let me save successfully the exe. Some tools did able to replace its app icon, but it didn't replace the tray icon either. Turn out it could either relies its tray icon on the system or it's hidden somewhere deeper the portable exe.

To those familiar on this and programming, can someone help me with this? How can I modify this one's tray icon. Even on advanced tools like Visual Studio just to make it happen

Comment: Your question is not about portable apps in general, it's only about iBrightness. Please [edit] your title.

Comment: Try with [PE explorer](http://www.pe-explorer.com/).